# Convert multiple image dataURI's into a video using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, video, webm

I am having a sequences of image frames in a dataURI base64 format. I need to merge all those data's and convert it into a video (.webm) format in javascript. 
Anyone suggest me the method to do so?

Comment: This is **not** a job for client side javascript

Comment: @muthu, in node.js I would recommend you taking a look at [ffmpeg](//www.ffmpeg.org/). It can convert image-sequences to videos (different formats, including .webm), although I'm not sure wether you would have to save the images to disk first, or can provide them as a stream.